# Unable to connect to Oracle 10g XE

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, database-connection, sqlexception

My code :

```
package java_connect;

import java.sql.*;

public class JdbcOracleXe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe", "username",
                "password");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    }
}
```

Error message :

```
-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------
Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!
Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at java_connect.JdbcOracleXe.main(JdbcOracleXe.java:28)
```

Comment: So, do you have an Oracle database running and listening on port 1521 on your own machine? It seems not.

Comment: Please could you add the rest of that stack trace, ideally we'd be able to confirm whether or not the connection was looking for port 1521 on host localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the database up.  Seems like the database may be down and hence you are not able to connect